# SharePoint REST show current user profile picture

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365-apps, office365-restapi

When getting the URL from the current user's profile via REST, the image tag is not able to display when the src is updated:

```
<img id="escMyPic" src="" alt="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: strURL + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: MyPictureSucceeded,
    error: MyPictureFailed
});
function MyPictureSucceeded(data) {
    if(data.d.PictureUrl != null) {
        $('#escMyPic').attr('src', data.d.PictureUrl);
    }
}
function MyPictureFailed() {
        alert('Error: Unexpected error loading profile picture.');
}
</script>
```

The return url looks like this in SharePoint Online:
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com:443/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/email_address_MThumb.jpg?t=63601764394

It redirects to:
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/email_address_MThumb.jpg?t=63601764394

Using browser dev tools, you see the mime type that comes back is not image/jpg but text/plain.  I've removed the query string parameter, and even placed the hard coded URL in the image tag src, but it just doesn't display.  Also the response body in the dev tools is blank.  It appears to be redirecting and authenticating before showing.

When placing the hard coded URL in the browser address bar, the picture shows fine, and the dev tools response header shows the picture as the contents of the URL, and the MIME type is image/jpg.

How do you get the profile image to show from a REST call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to `/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties` endpoint which returns `PersonalUrl` property, user profile picture could be requested via `_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=<size>&accountname=<accountname>` page, where

- `size` - could be set to `S/M/L` which stands for Small/Medium/Large
  image size
- `accountname` - user account name

**Example**

```
var url = getMyPictureUrl(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName,"M");
$('#escMyPic').attr('src', url);
```

where

```
function getMyPictureUrl(webUrl,accountName,size){
    return webUrl + "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=" + size + "&accountname=" + accountName;
}
```

Comment: Whats the account name here? is it email address? Or `i:0#.f|membership|emailAddress` format? Because every time I am getting default image. Also I am trying to get the profile image of other users, not the current logged in users.

Comment: Second one, `accountName` needs to be provided in claims format

Comment: Use "siteAbsoluteUrl" instead of "webAbsoluteUrl".